# Product of a disjoint cycle

Tags: group-theory, permutation-cycles

Would somebody help me with part (b) the following question?

I have proven part (a) but have no idea how to do (b).

Thank you!

Comment: This is actually a theorem "Then σ and ρ are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle type." [check here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Conjugate_Permutations_have_Same_Cycle_Type)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

If $\gamma=(a_1\,a_2\,\dots\,a_r)$ is a cycle  in the decomposition of the permutation $\sigma_1$, $\tau\gamma\tau^{-1}$ is the cycle
$$\bigl(\tau(a_1)\,\tau(a_2)\,\dots\,\tau(a_r)\bigr),$$
so the question is really: given any two cycles with the same length, can you find a permutation that maps one cycle onto the other?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
Let 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sigma_1&=&(a_{1,1}a_{1,2} \cdots a_{1,l_1}) (a_{2,1}a_{2,2} \cdots a_{2,l_2}) \cdots (a_{r,1}a_{r,2} \cdots a_{r,l_r}) \\
\sigma_2&=&(b_{1,1}b_{1,2} \cdots b_{1,l_1}) (b_{2,1}b_{2,2} \cdots b_{2,l_2}) \cdots (b_{r,1}b_{r,2} \cdots b_{r,l_r}). \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now if $ \sigma_2 =\tau \sigma_1 \tau^{-1}$ then $ \tau= ?$